# php no retorna correctamente al ajax en host pero si en xampp

Tags: jquery, ajax, xampp, hosting, telegram

He creado un formulario para enviar mensajes a Telegram a traves de un bot. Utilizo ajax para enviar todos los datos de mi formulario a mi codigo php y que en este se genere el link del envio del mensaje.
En mi ajax tengo un success y error, y aqui el problema:

Cuando ejecuto mi codigo en el Xampp todo marcha bien y se envian los mensajes y el link se va al success y se muestra, pero al ejecutar en el localhost de Netbeans no funciona y al error llega "object Object", en mi hosting parece realizarse y llega al success pero no se envian los mensajes.

Este es el formulario:

```
            <form method="post" id="formu" autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Enviar mensaje a José</legend>
                    <label for="nomb">Nombre</label>
                    <input id="nomb" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="tu nombre">
                    <label for="asunt">Asunto</label>
                    <input id="asunt" name="asunto" type="text" placeholder="opcional">
                    <label for="mail">E-mail</label>
                    <input id="mail" name="correo" type="text" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com">
                    <br>
                    <textarea id="msj" name="mensaje" rows="5" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje"></textarea>
                    <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="post()"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Este el javascript:

```
function post() {
    alert("Enviando.....");
    var formulario = $("#formu").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'bot.php',
        data: formulario,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Enviado correctamente"+result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("No se envio"+result);
        }
    });
}
```

y este mi bot.php :

```
<?php
define('BOT_TOKEN', '344659915:AAEQQbBhXcovEWgj4UkSMnoin1XP8P2TsZE');
define('CHAT_ID', '442754015');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot');
$msj=$_POST['nombre'].", 
".$_POST['asunto']."\n\n".$_POST['mensaje']."\n".$_POST['correo'];
$queryArray = ['chat_id'=>CHAT_ID,'text'=> $msj];
$url=API_URL.BOT_TOKEN.'/sendMessage?'.http_build_query($queryArray);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
//header("Location: ".$url);
//echo file_get_contents($url,"UTF-8");
?>
```

Las partes de codigo comentadas en bot.php las tengo porque son envios validos para hacer funcionar el codigo, pero como dije solo sucede en el xampp.

Cabe decir que todo esta importado en mi html, el jquery-3.2.1.js y mi javascript con mi funcion post().

aqui mi hosting: joseluna.ml

Comment: El envío se hace correctamente. Pero los objetos no se ven con alert, si quieres ver el objeto, dentro del `success` tienes que hacer algo como: `console.log(result);`, así podrás ver en la consola lo que devuelve el servidor.

Comment: Yo no veo que en tu `bot.php` estes imprimiendo nada. El contenido de `result` es simplemente una cadena vacía. El comportamiento distinto entre tu XAMPP local y el servidor remoto puede deberse a diferencias en el `php.ini`. Por ejemplo, que en el remoto tengas deshabilitado el parámetro `allow_url_fopen`. (http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)

Comment: al bot.php le agregué al final

    echo $url;

entonces ya en mi alert se ve el url para el envio del mensaje, pero sigue lo mismo, no se realiza. No requiero ver los objetos, lo que sucede es que no se lleva a cabo la accion del codigo php.